# Upper-Bounded and Lower-Bounded Wildcards in return type of Java Generic method

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, generic-method

I was trying to solve a problem where I am not able to understand part of the answer.

Following is the class `BackLister`:

```
public class BackLister {
    // INSERT HERE
    {
        List<T> output = new LinkedList<T>();
        for (T t : input)
            output.add(0, t);
        return output;
    }
}
```

The question asks which can be inserted at `// INSERT HERE` in the `BackLister` class to compile and run without error?

Following are the options:

```
A. public static <T> List<T> backwards(List<T> input)
B. public static <T> List<T> backwards(List<? extends T> input)
C. public static <T> List<T> backwards(List<? super T> input)
D. public static <T> List<? extends T> backwards(List<T> input)
E. public static <T> List<? super T> backwards(List<T> input)
F. public static <? extends T> List<T> backwards(List<T> input)
G. public static <? super T> List<T> backwards(List<T> input)
```

I understand that that A and B are correct, as for `for (T t : input)` to work the elements in `input` should be of type `T` or subtype of `T`.

But I am not able to understand why `D` and `E` options are correct?

I understand the following:

1. `public static <T> List<? extends T> backwards(List<T> input)`
       means that the return type should be a `List` of `T` or subclass
       of `T`.
2. `public static <T> List<? super T> backwards(List<T> input)` means that the return type should be a `List` of `T` or
   superclass of `T`.

Could somebody help me understand it?

Comment: I think first of all what you understand is correct :)

Answer (score 5):

There is difference between each of them and I'm going to explain most of them. Let's start with our example. I use this class hierarchy:

```
class Food {}
class Apple extends Food {}
class Orange extends Food {}
class RedApple extends Apple {}

List<Food> listFood = new ArrayList<>();
List<Apple> listApple = new ArrayList<>();
List<Orange> listOrange = new ArrayList<>();
List<RedApple> listRedApple = new ArrayList<>();
```

ow start with first one:

```
A. public static <T> List<T> backwards(List<T> input)
```

This method will only accept `List<T>` and return `List<T>` and you can not send `listApple` and return `listRedApple`. (however your return list can contain `RedApple` because it extends `Apple` but type of list must be `List<Apple>` and nothing else)

```
B. public static <T> List<T> backwards(List<? extends T> input)
```

You can send `listRedApple` and return `listApple` but you know that `listRedApple` is **"? extend Apple"** so in the method body java recognize T as Apple. Then if you use can add elements in `listRedApple` which sent as argument, you can add `Apple` in `listRedApple` which is not true!!! so compiler avoid it and give compile error. In B you can only **read elements** (and get it as T) but you can not add anything to it.

```
C. public static <T> List<T> backwards(List<? super T> input)
```

You can send `listApple` and then in method body you can add anything extends `Apple` because compiler see T as `Apple` and in a list of **anything which is super of T**, you can add anything extends `Apple`.
However this time, you can not read anything because you don't know its type except you get it as `Object`. (It is a list of **"? super T"**)

As you see here there is difference between **? super** and **? extend**. one of them give you write access and other give you read access. This is the real use of wildcard.

```
D. public static <T> List<? extends T> backwards(List<T> input)
E. public static <T> List<? super T> backwards(List<T> input)
```

If you send `listApple` then you return `List<? extends Apple>` but you can's assign it to any of `listFood` or `listApple` or `listRedApple` because `List<? extends Apple>` maybe contain `Apple` or `RedApple` or something else and we can't assign it to any `List<T>` because then we can add `T` to that list and maybe `T` and `? extends T` is not same. this is same for both `D` and `E`. You can assign it to `List<? extends Apple>` for 'E and `List<? super Apple>` for `D` and send them to a method which need them as parameter.

```
F. public static <? extends T> List<T> backwards(List<T> input)
G. public static <? super T> List<T> backwards(List<T> input)
```

Give compile errors because wildcard can not used like this.

I hope this help you.
If something is wrong, any comment is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Options `D` and `E` are valid because there exist a *super-subtype* relationships among generic types that allow you to define a larger set of types that the method can accept or return.

Consequently, the following is valid (D):

```
public static <T> List<? extends T> backwards(List<T> input) {
    return List.of();
}

// there exist a super-subtype relationships among List<? extends Number> and List<Long>
List<? extends Number> list = backwards(List.<Long>of(1L, 2L));
```

because the type `Long` is a member of the type family that the wildcard `? extends Number` denotes (the family of types that are subtypes of `Number` and the type `Number` itself).

The next code snippet is also valid (E):

```
public static <T> List<? super T> backwards(List<T> input) {
    return List.of();
}

List<? super Long> ints = backwards(List.<Long>of(1L, 2L));
```

because the type `Long` is a member of the type family that the wildcard `? super Long` denotes (the family of types that are supertypes of `Long` and the type `Long` itself).

So, your understanding is correct.

[Further reading](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ207).

Answer (score 1):

Below image describes the sub-typing relation in Generics:

```
List<T> is a subtype of List<? super T>
Also List<T> is a subtype of List<? extends T>
```

This is why options D and E are correct.

[image]

You can refer the page : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html

Comment: @VGR On what basis do you say that? Did you check the link I have shared and the image?

Comment: Did you?  Quoting from that page: “Although `Integer` is a subtype of `Number`, `List<Integer>` is not a subtype of `List<Number>` and, in fact, these two types are not related.”

Comment: @VGR You are wrong because that’s not even what I said. Please read carefully the full page again and my answer. You are missing the significance of “?” totally. Also read the answers above which agree to my comment. If you have downvoted, you need to reconsider it!

Comment: They are related, but `List<T>` definitely is not a subtype of `List<? extends T>`.  My objection is to your use of “subtype,” which has a specific meaning and which is not accurate here.